# How to automatically open a popup input box when user starts typing

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to automatically capture keystrokes into a pop-up input box as soon as the user starts typing anything if the user is on a specific webpage/s.
It's similar to the image shown in a desktop software where the user starts typing and it's captured into an input box for the user to start a search.
[image: Trade Station Software]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mmarwaha/mdvg5kjo/1/

All I need is to be able to push this data into MySQL and display the results

Answer (score 0):

Check this out, https://jsfiddle.net/v1b3m/wmufgy1o/4/, I have used jquery, but you could as well do it with basic js, you can easily add a button to the popup, which when pressed will send the data to your database.

[Sample pop up with text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHTco.png)

```
let word = "";

$(document).keyup(event => {
// find which key has been pressed from the event object
const key = event.originalEvent.key;

// make the hidden modal visible
$("#myModal").css("display", "block");

const ignoreKeys = [
  "CapsLock",
  "Shift",
  "Tab",
  "Alt",
  "Control",
  "PageUp",
  "PageDown",
  "ArrowUp",
  "ArrowDown",
  "ArrowRight",
  "ArrowLeft",
  "Escape",
  "Home",
  "Insert"
 ];

if (ignoreKeys.indexOf(key) > -1) {
} else if (key == "Backspace" || key == "Delete") {
 word = word.substring(0, word.length - 1);
} else {
 word += key;
}

// Update the text content of the modal
$("#my-text").text(word);
});

$(".close").click(() => {
  $("#myModal").css("display", "none");
});
```